# How to calculate the largest possible common subnet among multiple IP addresses?

Tags: python, sql, visual-studio-code, ip, subnet

I have a CSV file containing all different IP addresses. And I want to find the largest possible common subnet along with its CIDR value among these IP addresses. For example, '35.168.107.193' and '34.199.153.226' both belong to 34.0.0.0/7.

FYI, I got a python code that is able to calculate the largest possible common subnet among two IP addresses. Is there any way this code can be revised so that I don't have to manually pass two arguments to the function and the program is able to scan through all the IP addresses in my CSV file rather than just two IP addresses?

import ipaddress

```
def calc_inclusive_subnet(ip1, ip2):  #accepts 2 IP strings
#make IP Address objects
ip1_obj=ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip1)
ip2_obj=ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip2) 

if ip1_obj<=ip2_obj:
    min_ip=ip1_obj
    max_ip=ip2_obj
else:
    min_ip=ip2_obj
    max_ip=ip1_obj

distance = int(max_ip)-int(min_ip)
ip_range=0 #increment powers of 2 until you have subnet distance
while 2**ip_range < distance:
    ip_range += 1

net = ipaddress.IPv4Network(str(min_ip) + '/' +str(32-ip_range), strict=False)
if max_ip not in net: 
# i.e. if the distance implies one size network, but IPs span 2
    ip_range+=1
    net = ipaddress.IPv4Network(str(min_ip) + '/' +str(32-ip_range), strict=False)

return net
```

Answer (score 1):

The *largest* possible IPv4 subnet is always 0.0.0.0/0. Likely, you're asking for the *smallest* subnet containing those addresses.

Rather than using try and error, you can

- convert both addresses to uint32
- *exclusive or* the converted addresses - same bits become 0, different bits become 1
- count 0 bits starting from bit 31 - the count is your prefix length